# Extra whitespace with ANT propertyregex

Tags: regex, ant, whitespace

I've been banging my head on this one all day. I have a string that I've captured from running a shell command, and I need to parse that string and pull out the path of a file. What I have works ok, until I try to copy that file... I think the regex I'm using is leaving a single whitespace character at the front of the path, which causes all sorts of trouble later.

Here's a sample of the input string:
     [echo] P4ant have output = //perforce/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7
/p4ant/p4ant-2010.1.293250.jar#1 - C:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\dir6\dir7
\dir8\dir9\p4ant\p4ant-2010.1.293250.jar

And when I parse it I get this:
     [echo] P4ant local path =  C:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\dir6\dir7
\dir8\dir9\p4ant\p4ant-2010.1.293250.jar

Which looks ok, but there's an extra space there. I can't seem to get rid of it. 
Here's the code I'm using:

```
            <propertyregex property="p4ant.local.path"
                  input="${p4ant.have.output}"
                  regexp="([^-][^ ]+?)$"
                  select="\0"
                  casesensitive="false"
            />
```

I'm searching for the "dash space" combination, and it doesn't include the dash in the output, but still includes the space for some reason.

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
\-\s <-- dash, followed by a whitespace
(.+?) <-- Anything, up to the next matching character
\s  <-- whitespace
(.+)$  <-- Anything, up to the end
```

So: 
    `regexp="\-\s(.+?)\s(.+)$"`

Then concatenate $1 and $2 (Sorry, don't know how this works in ANT)